# JSTL getting values from Object array

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

My action class has an object array like this:

```
Object[] varCount = (Object[]) countList.get(0);
```

and my debug shows values for varCount. I put this object array in model as follows:

```
model.put("varCount ", varCount );
```

and in JSP I iterate as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="varCount " items="${model.varCount }" varStatus="loop">
  <tr>
     <td align="center">&nbsp;<c:out value="${varCount[0]}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And I get the following error:

```
Wrapped exception:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "value" with value "${varCount [0]}": Unable to find a value for "0" in object of class "java.math.BigDecimal" using operator "[]" (null)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:306)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:16
```

How do I get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this to get all array objects

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${model.varCount }" varStatus="loop">
 <tr>
 <td align="center">&nbsp;<c:out value="${item}"/></td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I have to get all the elements from 0 to 10.

Comment: As you are iterating through the Object array, each iteration gets one single object from the array. I presume each object is a BigDecimal in this array.

Comment: Just to say, you used <c:out value="${varCount[0]}"/>, which doesn't make sense as ${varCount} itself is your object in the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`model.varCount` is an array or objects, containing BigDecimal instances.

The forEach loop iterates through all the elements of this array. At each iteration, the current element is stored in the `varCount` page attribute. The current element is an instance of `BigDecimal`. `varCount[0]` thus doesn't make sense.